# How do I create an auto-incrementing index/a sequence for an OrientDB database using the Java Document API?

Tags: java, orientdb

I am using OrientDB with Java via its Document API. I have a simple Class called `items` which has an attribute `ID`. I explicitly declare the schema like this:

```
    OSchema schema = db.getMetadata().getSchema();
    OClass itemsClass = schema.createClass("items");
    itemsClass.createProperty("ID", OType.LONG);
```

and then create an index on `ID`: `CREATE INDEX items.ID ON items (ID) UNIQUE`.

Now when I create a new item (something like `ODocument doc = new ODocument("items")` etc.), I would like the ID for the new item to be generated on the database (something like a sequence in RDBMS). 
How do I do this with the Java Document API for OrientDB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OrientDB doesn't support serial (we've an [issue](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/367) for that), so you can manage your own counter in this way (example using SQL):

```
create class counter
insert into counter set name='mycounter', value=0
```

And then every time you need a new number you can do:

```
update counter incr value = 1 where name = 'mycounter'
```

This works in a SQL batch in this way:

```
begin
let $counter = update counter incr value = 1 where name = 'mycounter' return after
insert into items set id = $counter.value, qty = 10, price = 1000
commit
```

By using Java you can make the same: create singleton class "Counters" that everytime increment the document value and save it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works!

I created a counter class and implemented a `long getNewItemID()` method in my DAO which executes thecommand `"UPDATE counters INCREMENT value = 1 WHERE name='items'` and then queries the db via a `OSQLSynchQuery` `SELECT value FROM counters WHERE name='items'`.
This way I can create and easily return the ID and use it in my method to create an item in the DB even within a transaction, so I guess this should be safe for multiple clients.

Comment: Very nice that you guys hang around here. +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from OrientDB 2.2 Sequences are now supported

http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Sequences-and-auto-increment.html