# OrientDB use cluster position as an identifier

Tags: orientdb

I would like to have an auto-increment identifier on my persisted orientdb entities.

The id in an orient database is the [RecordID](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Concepts#recordid). It is composed of two parts (`cluster:position`)

- cluster, is the cluster id.
- position, is the absolute position of the record inside a cluster.

I saw in the documentation that by default OrientDB creates **1 cluster per class**. 
Since there is one entity class per cluster. 
Is it possible to use only the RecordID **position** as an identifier (unique for a class) for my objects ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely yes. The RID is never recycled, even on record deletion and represents the record as unique object in a database.

Comment: Ok Thanks Luca. That is a good news. Is there some pros/cons (design, performance...) to do this instead of an [ad hoc sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24821946/1594933) ?

Comment: pros: it's the fastest thing ever. cons: handling # could be a problem in HTTP/web

Comment: I would like to use only the right part as an identifier not the full record id. This would be a unique identifier for a class.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. i will edit my question.

Comment: Ok, then you have no cons against SEQUENCEs

Comment: But why not using the cluster position. I will have no additional sequence to maintain ?

Comment: By default is 1 class - 1 cluster. But if you create a cluster "employee_usa" and "employee_europe" under the same class "Employee", you'd have 2 sequences of rids for boh clusters, so using only cluster-position is not enough.